# SAS: prevent proc report from applying comma format to display header title

Tags: sas, format, report, ods

I'm generating tables with rolling weeks of data, so my columns have to be named in the `yyyymmdd` format like `20161107`. I need to apply a comma format to these columns to display counts, but the format is also being applied to the column name so `20161107` turns into `20,161,107`. Below is example code that shows the error:

```
data fish; set sashelp.fish; 
    TEST = WIDTH*1000;
run;

ods tagsets.excelxp file = "C:\User\Desktop\test.xls" style=minimal
    options(embedded_titles="yes" autofit_height="yes" autofilter="all");

proc report data = fish spanrows nowd &header_style.;
    column SPECIES TEST;
    define SPECIES / display;
    define TEST / display "20161107" 
        f=comma12. style={tagattr='format:###,###,###'}; /* ERROR OCCURS WITH THIS STYLE */
    title1 bold "sashelp.fish title";
run; title1;

ods tagsets.excelxp close;
```

It looks like I can fix this error by padding the display name with spaces like `" 20161107 "` but I'm not hardcoding these names, so I'd like to try to fix it in the `proc report` syntax first if possible. Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

You should tell SAS to only apply that style to the column, then:

```
define TEST / display "20161107" 
    f=comma12. style(column)={tagattr='format:###,###,###'};
```

Then it should work as you expect.

Styles in `PROC REPORT` typically have multiple things they can apply to, and if you don't specify which they apply to all.  `style(header)`, `style(report)`, etc. are all options - you can see the full list, plus a good explanation, in the SAS paper [Using Style Elements in the REPORT and TABULATE procedures](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/stylesinprocs.pdf).